# Use \large and \large environment twice simultaneously

Tags: fonts, pdftex, fontsize

[image]

See the text above "Notation", I want the "N" to be a little bit larger than "OTATION", the rest of the sentence but again I want the whole a little bit larger.
So I giving \large {{\large N}OTATION: $\mathbb{R}$ denotes the real numbers.}
It is not working.
Could you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you want small caps instead

Comment: yes, yes. I want small caps letters little bit larger

Comment: You want egreg's answer.  But the reason your approach didn't work is that `\large` just makes the text size "large" (whatever that is).  It doesn't make it "larger than it would have otherwise been".  So you could have used a true abomination of `{\Large N}{\large otation:}...`.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking for small caps, actually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\textsc{Notation}: $\mathbb{R}$ denotes the real numbers

\bigskip

\noindent
\textsc{\large Notation}: $\mathbb{R}$ denotes the real numbers

\bigskip

\noindent
\textsc{\Large Notation}: $\mathbb{R}$ denotes the real numbers

\end{document}
```

In order: good, bad and ugly.

[image]

Why is the first one good and the other two aren't? Because the small caps already provide sufficent emphasis to the reader's eye and increasing the font size just interrupts the flow. Different font sizes should almost never be mixed in the same line of type.